# Two idential datetimes; one shows 12 hour the other 24 hour

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a form with two datetime fields. The user inputs the date (yyyy-mm-dd) and time (3 boxes; hour, minute, am/pm).

For some reason, the first one isn't getting saved as a 24 hour time.

The following data is the result of entering:

2011-1-1
4:30 PM

I am using strtotime() to convert a string to a datetime format.

```
$dateOccured = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateOccurred));
$dateResolved = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateResolved));
```

If I use print_r() to look at the results of this, it is showing correctly.

Date Occurred:

```
[year] => 2011
[month] => 1
[day] => 1
[hour] => 16
[minute] => 30
[second] => 0
[fraction] => 0
[warning_count] => 0
```

Date Resolved

```
[year] => 2011
[month] => 1
[day] => 1
[hour] => 16
[minute] => 30
[second] => 0
[fraction] => 0
[warning_count] => 0
```

Both show the correct time: 16:30 (or 4:30PM). When I look in my database, this is what is shown.

Date Occurred

```
2011-01-01 04:30:00
```

Date Resolved

```
2011-01-01 16:30:00
```

I know it's a problem with the dateOccurred variable because if I replace it with dateResolved in my query, it gets inserted correctly. What I can't figure out is where the problem is? What am I missing that is causing this?

Thank you.

---

If it was the database, wouldn't replacing the dateOccurred variable with dateResolved in the query not matter? 
Here is the INSERT query

```
"INSERT INTO 
  incidents (
    incidentNumber, date, itFunction, issue, severity,
    owner, dateOccurred, dateResolved, locationsImpacted, businessImpact,
    rcaRequired, rcaReceived, rootCause, notes) 
VALUES (
  '{$incidentNumber}', '{$date}', '{$itFunction}', '{$issue}', '{$severity}',
  '{$owner}', '{$dateOccurred}', '{$dateResolved}', '{$locationsImpacted}', '{$businessImpact}',
  '{$rcaRequired}', '{$rcaReceived}', '{$rootCause}', '{$notes}')"
```

They are both datetime fields.

Comment: If the code is identical the problem must be a setting in the DB.

Comment: What does the insert command look like, and what are the data types on both columns in the table?

Comment: If it was the database, wouldn't replacing the dateOccurred variable with dateResolved in the query not matter? Here is the query `"INSERT INTO incidents (incidentNumber, date, itFunction, issue, severity, owner, dateOccurred, dateResolved, locationsImpacted, businessImpact, rcaRequired, rcaReceived, rootCause, notes) VALUES('{$incidentNumber}', '{$date}', '{$itFunction}', '{$issue}', '{$severity}', '{$owner}', '{$dateOccurred}', '{$dateResolved}', '{$locationsImpacted}', '{$businessImpact}', '{$rcaRequired}', '{$rcaReceived}', '{$rootCause}', '{$notes}')"` They are both datetime fields.

Comment: Are you trying to insert the data into the DB as 12-hour format? Convert them to 24h in php before your insert.

Comment: Found the problem...typos! I've been bashing my head against the wall for an hour trying to figure this out! $dateOccured (single R...rrrrrr)! Put this one in the embarrassing column.

Comment: You can find errors like that by setting `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE)`.

Comment: some database setting? Like 12/24 hour format?

Comment: @navalhawkeye Consider posting your solution as an answer that you can select. It will show the question as resolved and possibly help you earn [a badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner).

Comment: @JYelton, I will do so, thank you. Apparently I have to wait 6 more hours before I can though.

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem...typos! I've been bashing my head against the wall for an hour trying to figure this out! `$dateOccured` (single R...rrrrrr)! Put this one in the embarrassing column.

I learned that error reporting can be made more useful by using

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE)
```

Thanks to Chronial for that.

Comment: I can't believe you got three upvotes for this. Have another one.